# Show PopOver for TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying show popOver for my one of textFields, I want to when tap textField for showing pop over keyboard not showing and I can change text field text with popOver, but when tap to text field, text field resign first responder not work there is my code.

```
 func textDidBeginEditing(sender:UITextField) -> Void
    {
        showPopOver()
    }
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var maxLength = Int()
        var newString = NSString()
        if textField == textField1 {
            maxLength = 2
            let currentString: NSString = textField.text!
            if string.characters.count > 0 {
                newString =  currentString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

            }
        }
        else if textField == textField2 {

            textField2.resignFirstResponder()
            showPopOver()

        }


        else  if textField == textField3 {
            maxLength = 3
            let currentString: NSString = textField.text!
            if string.characters.count > 0 {
                newString =  currentString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

            }
        }
        else  if textField == textField4 {
            maxLength = 2
            let currentString: NSString = textField.text!
            if string.characters.count > 0 {
                newString =  currentString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

            }
        }

        return newString.length <= maxLength
    }
```